# Joining null in SQL Server, Oracle and informatica

Tags: sql-server, oracle, informatica

I have two tables to join with a column (say `emp_id`).. if `emp_id` in both the tables have null values, how will **SQL Server** and **Oracle** treat???

Coz, I read that **informatica** will neglect the NULL rows when joining..if I handle the null, by substituting -1, a cross-join will happen which i don't want..

What can I do here?

I cannot completely neglect the rows which has NULL.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the rows with NULL values?

Comment: only the id column have NULLs..all the other column have values, i want them

Comment: Yes, but what are you joining on? If nothing, then see my answer below.

Comment: Having reread the question I think Doug's interpretation of your needs is probably more along the right lines than mine but it would help if you flesh your scenario out a bit.

Comment: I don't understand your situation either. If you have, say, two rows in master table and two rows in detail table, with emp_id null on all four rows, what exactly do you want to get out of that join equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want a `left outer join`? See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Here's how you do it with [Oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_left_outer_join.htm)

Here's the [SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178429%28SQL.80%29.aspx) for `left outer join`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't join on colA = colB and expect NULLs to compare as equal. Depending on your needs (assuming perhaps some sort of table synchronisation need below) three approaches I can think of are

1. Use COALESCE to substitute a value such as -1 in place of null if a suitable value exists that can never occur in your actual data. `COALESCE(Table1.colA,-1) = COALESCE(Table2.colB,-1)`
2. Use both an IS NULL and equality check on all joining columns.
3. Use INTERSECT (nulls will be treated as equal). Possibly in a derived table that you can JOIN back onto.

Comment: if i substitute -1 will a cross-join happen?

Comment: No but it's quite inefficient so probably not very suitable for large amounts of rows. Can you clarify your situation why you need to do this? I am assuming that you will also be having some non null columns in your join. e.g. to synchronise 2 copies of a table. If this is not the case you will get a cross join yes.

Comment: i haven't faced a real-world scenario like this..just a doubt..so, what'll u do if the ID column's have null values?

Comment: Well generally your id columnn wouldn't be null in its "main" table as presumably it is there to uniquely identify a row. If it is in a FK table and it is null then it wouldn't make sense for NULL to join onto anything.